# Formula for collision frequency and mean free path

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws, kinetic-theory-of-gases, ideal-gas

We were studying collision frequency and mean free path today, and in it, we got the equations of collision frequency as:
$$Z=\sqrt 2 \pi \sigma^2v_{rms}N$$
where $N$ is the number density, equal to $n/V$.

Then, I looked online for more information, but surprisingly, I got completely different formulae for $Z$ itself.
One formula was $Z=\frac1{\sqrt 2}\pi\sigma^2v_{avg}N^2$. Another was $Z=\sqrt 2\pi\sigma^2v_{avg}\frac{N} V$.

Similarly, the formula for mean free path given was $\lambda= \frac{V_{rms}} Z$. So, changing the value of $Z$ would obviously change the value of $\lambda$ as well.

Also, all these formulae in all the different websites appear to come with really complex mathematics and physics which I don't really understand, so if anyone could give a simpler explanation, that would be nice.

Comment: This has to do with collisions between like or unlike molecules as well as a factor of $\sqrt{2}$ from going from average velocity to RMS. See McQuarrie $\it{Statistical\, Mechanics}$ (1976), p. 371-372.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you yourself not answer?

Comment: I am struggling with the same question and didn't find any reliable explanation.